# Locale-dependent PHP functions

Tags: php, hosting, locale

I’m moving a PHP website to a hosting that unfortunatelly doesn’t support ru_RU.cp1251 locale which the site uses extensively. The only way out of the problems I can see is to refactor the code such that it becomes locale-independent. Is there a way to safely do this? For example is there a list of all native PHP functions that can depend on current locale?

Comment: is it an option to ask for a install of the `ru_RU.cp1251` locale?

Comment: Why are you moving the site to a host that does not meet your requirements?

Comment: Also I bet you have already googled for that. Why don't you show your-so-far compiled list if installing the locale or getting a host with proper locale is such burden? http://kitzlr.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/locale-dependent-behaviour-of-php/

Comment: Unfortunatelly the only hosting provider that meets my requirements apart from this only thing is the one that can't install this locale. I'm not happy with this but after days of consideration I don't see any other option.

Comment: Then compile your list and add it as an answer. You're welcome to answer your own question. After you've made the move you'll notice from time to time the parts that were not obvious upfront and you can use the answer to document that.

Comment: I also will link questions to here if I think they might be related to locale dependency and are about some PHP function.