# PHP escape shell arg unwanted behaviour

Tags: php, shell, encoding

When I do [`escapeshellarg('référencement')`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)  it returns 'rfrencement'. How can we resolve the problem ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://codepad.org/A3Eva7kn - you might have hidden dependencies on your system. Locate them and describe them in your question. The systemadministrator of the computer you're using might be able to offer you more information about the dependencies that create this side-effect. Related: [Locale-dependent PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12942088/367456)

Comment: edit your posting to include your required output. Good luck.

Comment: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Comment: You can get the set locale with `var_dump(setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""));` - the output should shed some more light. See as well: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html - that is the underlying system function PHP calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to your system locale. What string encoding are you using for your argument, versus the encoding set as the locale? As a debugging step, you can try forcing UTF-8 with

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

before you call `escapeshellarg`, and see if that helps.

Comment: In the terminal echo $LNAG just returned  en_US.UTF-8. But I also tried setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");  same result . BTW echo 'référencement'  returns 'rÃ©fÃ©rencement'

Comment: How are you viewing the result? Is your terminal/page text encoding set to UTF8?

Comment: I am running that inside the terminal . Honestly didn understand the question

Comment: FYI: `rÃ©fÃ©rencement` - that is UTF-8 displayed as ISO-8859-1 - this would be invalid UTF-8 then and the invalid byte sequeneces dropped create your outcome. check the encoding of your PHP file that it matches with the system filenames. You need to do some alignment here to get this safe.

Comment: Your terminal may be set to interpret results as ISO-8859. Can you see any UTF-8 returned by the server?